# PDF for sum of two Gaussian random vectors with noise

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{x}; \boldsymbol{\mu}, \mathsf{\Sigma})$ be a multivariate Gaussian Probability Density Function (PDF), so

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{x};\boldsymbol{\mu},\mathsf{\Sigma}) := 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\det2\pi\mathsf{\Sigma}}}
\exp\Big(-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu})^{\top}\mathsf{\Sigma}^{-1}(\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu})\Big),
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{x}, \boldsymbol{\mu} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathsf{\Sigma} \in \mathbb{R}^{m,m}$ is Symmetric Positive Definite (SPD). Let $\mathbf{Y}_1$ and $\mathbf{Y}_2$ be two random vectors with the following joint PDF

\begin{equation*}
p_{\mathbf{Y}_{1}, \mathbf{Y}_{2}}(\mathbf{y}_{1}, \mathbf{y}_{2}) =
\mathcal{N} \left(
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{y}_1 \\
\mathbf{y}_2
\end{bmatrix} ;
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{0}_n \\
\mathbf{0}_m
\end{bmatrix} ,
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathsf{\Sigma}_{11} & \mathsf{\Sigma}_{12} \\
\mathsf{\Sigma}_{21} & \mathsf{\Sigma}_{22} 
\end{bmatrix}
\right) \cdot
\end{equation*}

Furthermore, let $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{E}}$ be a Gaussian noise vector with PDF  $p_{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{E}}}(\boldsymbol{\epsilon})=\mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\epsilon}; \mathbf{0}, \sigma_{\epsilon}^2\mathsf{I_n})$, which is independent of $\mathbf{Y}_1$ and $\mathbf{Y}_2$. Define $\mathbf{Z}_1=\mathbf{Y}_1+\boldsymbol{\mathcal{E}}$. The question is to find the joint PDF $p_{\mathbf{Z}_{1}, \mathbf{Y}_{2}}(\mathbf{z}_{1}, \mathbf{y}_{2})$. I have been told that the answer is

\begin{equation*}
p_{\mathbf{Z}_{1}, \mathbf{Y}_{2}}(\mathbf{z}_{1}, \mathbf{y}_{2}) =
\mathcal{N} \left(
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{z}_1 \\
\mathbf{y}_2
\end{bmatrix} ;
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{0}_n \\
\mathbf{0}_m
\end{bmatrix} ,
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathsf{\Sigma}_{11}+\sigma_{\epsilon}^2\mathsf{I} & \mathsf{\Sigma}_{12} \\
\mathsf{\Sigma}_{21} & \mathsf{\Sigma}_{22} 
\end{bmatrix}
\right)\cdot
\end{equation*}

**My Thoughts**

By the marginalization property of Gaussians, we can conclude $p_{\mathbf{Y}_1}(\mathbf{y}_1)=\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{y}_1; \mathbf{0}_n,\mathsf{\Sigma}_{11})$ and $p_{\mathbf{Y}_2}(\mathbf{y}_2)=\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{y}_2; \mathbf{0}_m,\mathsf{\Sigma}_{22})$. I know that by the convolution theorem, the PDF for the sum of two independent random vectors is the convolution of their PDF. Furthermore, I know that the convolution of two Gaussians is a Gaussian. This implies that $\mathbf{Z}_1$ is Gaussian. We can also obtain its mean by linearity of expectation

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(Z_{1,i}) &=  \mathbb{E}(Y_{1,i}) +  \mathbb{E}(\mathcal{E}_{1,i}) = 0 + 0 = 0,
\end{align*}

and its covariance by bilinearity and symmetry of covariance as

\begin{align*}
\text{cov}(Z_{1,i},Z_{1,j}) &= \text{cov}(Y_{1,i},Y_{1,j}) + \text{cov}(\mathcal{E}_{i},\mathcal{E}_{j}) + 2 \text{cov}(Y_{1,i},\mathcal{E}_{j}) \\
&= \text{cov}(Y_{1,i},Y_{1,j}) + \sigma_{\epsilon}^2\,\delta_{ij} + 0 \\
&= (\mathsf{\Sigma}_{11})_{ij} + \sigma_{\epsilon}^2\,\delta_{ij},
\end{align*}

where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker's delta. So, we have $p_{\mathbf{Z}_1}(\mathbf{z}_1)=\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{z}_1; \mathbf{0}_n,\mathsf{\Sigma}_{11}+\sigma_{\epsilon}\mathsf{I}_n)$. But I don't know how to calculate $p_{\mathbf{Z}_{1}, \mathbf{Y}_{2}}(\mathbf{z}_{1}, \mathbf{y}_{2})$.

Comment: Is the noise vector independent *only* of $Y_1$?

Comment: @Snoop: mmmm, I think we can also assume that it is independent of both $\mathbf{Y}_1$ and $\mathbf{Y}_2$. Does this help?

Comment: What are the components of the covariance matrix of z1 and y2? You just need to put the pieces together.

Comment: @Eric: I didn't get you. Could you write an answer in detail? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is normally distributed with covariance matrix $\Sigma$ and $\varepsilon:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^m,m<n$ is normally distributed with covariance matrix $\Gamma$ and independent of $X$. Then, $Y=X+(\varepsilon,0_{n-m})$ is normally distributed with covariance matrix

$$\Sigma^*=\Sigma+\begin{bmatrix}\Gamma&0_{m\times n-m}\\
0_{n-m\times m}&0_{n-m\times n-m}\end{bmatrix}=\Sigma +\Gamma_0$$

To see this, let $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and calculate the moment generating function of $Y$ as follows

$$\begin{aligned}
M_{Y}(\xi)=E[e^{\xi^{\top}Y}]&=E[e^{\xi^{\top}X+\xi^{\top}(\varepsilon,0_{n-m})}]\\
&=E[e^{\xi^{\top} X}]E[e^{\xi_1\varepsilon_1 +...+\xi_m \varepsilon_m}]\\
&=E[e^{\xi^{\top} X}]E[e^{(\xi_1,...,\xi_m)^{\top} \varepsilon}]\\
&=e^{\xi^{\top}\Sigma \xi/2}e^{(\xi_1,...,\xi_m)^{\top}\Gamma (\xi_1,...,\xi_m)/2}\\
&=e^{\xi^{\top}\Sigma \xi/2}e^{\xi^{\top} \Gamma_0 \xi/2}\\
&=e^{\xi^{\top}(\Sigma + \Gamma_0)\xi/2}\\
&=e^{\xi^{\top}\Sigma^*\xi/2}\end{aligned},$$

where the formula for the moment generating function of a multivariate Gaussian is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3581821/moment-generating-function-for-multivariate-normal/3581889#3581889).

Comment: @HoseinRahnama you're welcome

Comment: I was thinking the other day about this solution and was wondering if $(\varepsilon,0_{n-m})$ really justifies as a *continuous* random variable. I mean, a random variable which is constant cannot be continuous. right?

Comment: Why should this be a problem? Our aim is to prove that $Y$ is normally distributed with some specific parameters. @HoseinRahnama

Comment: I think $(\varepsilon,0_{n-m})$ is probably a mixed random variable. Its covariance matrix is not even positive definite as is mentioned in the definition of a multivariate normal distribution. We may need something like dirac-delta to formalize this or at least be more accurate. I feel that the result still holds true but it has such subtleties.

Comment: @HoseinRahnama I understand your concern, but we can safely say that no distributional properties of $(\varepsilon,0_{n-m})$ are ever used in the argument. Only the simple fact that $\xi^{\top}(\varepsilon,0_{n-m})=(\xi_1,...,\xi_m)^{\top}\varepsilon$ is used.

Comment: I see, it seems that I was trying in mind to justify $(\varepsilon,0_{n-m})$ as a continuous normal random variable, which in fact is not true, right? and not even needed! :)

Comment: Indeed it is not needed to characterize the distribution of such random variable here :). It is not a trivial object in my opinion so it may deserve its own question. @HoseinRahnama

Answer (score 0):

$(Y_1,Y_2)$ is a multivariate Gaussian with covariance $\Sigma$. $\epsilon$ is Gaussian with variance $\sigma^2$, so $(\epsilon,0)$ is Gaussian with covariance matrix being $\sigma^2$ in the top left and 0’s elsewhere. If $A$ and $B$ are independent,

\begin{align}
\text{Cov} (A+B,A+B) &= \text{Cov}(A)+\text{Cov}(A,B)+\text{Cov}(B,A)+\text{Cov}(B,B) \\
&= \text{Cov}(A,A)+\text{Cov}(B,B)
\end{align}

We have that the sum of independent multivariate Gaussians is multivariate Gaussian whose mean is the sum of the means (by linearity) and whose covariance is the sum of the covariance (from above), so the mean of $(Z_1,Y_2)$ is $0$ and it’s covariance is the sun of the covariances:

\begin{bmatrix}
\mathsf{\Sigma}_{11}+\sigma^2\mathsf{I} & \mathsf{\Sigma}_{12} \\
\mathsf{\Sigma}_{21} & \mathsf{\Sigma}_{22} 
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Eric, it seems that $(\epsilon, 0)$ is not Gaussian as its covariance matrix is singular. There seems to be a bug in your argument. :) Indeed, $(\epsilon, 0)$ is not a continuous random vector but it is a mixed random vector and to do calculations with such random vectors we need dirac-delta and stuff like that.

Comment: Err, ok, but that doesn’t really matter to the calculation. If it makes you feel better, we can add $\epsilon_2$ to all the zero terms and then take the result as it approaches 0.

Comment: It would be good if you point this out in your answer to avoid confusion of future readers. :)